# Best way to get data from another server, process and display in front-end

Tags: php, curl

May be my question is looking for an opinion, but my research in the Internet didn't given me a sound idea.

This is a test project provided for our team in the institute where I learn to improve our R&D skills and problem solving techniques.

Project Description:

There are n number of users registered in our project. The users data are stored in Database tables. One database user with SELECT, UPDATE privileges are provided. The instructor asked us to create a service to perform some database operations. 1. Login & Registration, 2. Create some basic profile for his account, 3. Update Profile.

So for login, registration purposes we created to PHP folders. One for the Front-end and the other for the database operations. The reason why we proceeded like this is to separate the PHP files for front-end operations and the PHP files which perform the Database operations. Because separating these two reduces the possibility of breaching of the Database with the available code. If our public website is hacked the hacker may only have the basic HTML and PHP files, he may not get the details of the Database name, Database user, Encryption key etc., which are in the second server.

So the *login.php* in the first project will get, sanitize the user inputs and sends the data to the second server and the second server checks the user password hash against the email and return the response in JSON format back to the first server. Based on the JSON response the user will be redirected or any intended operations will be performed.

Note: Sanitization is done in the second server before Database operations too.

The doubts I have are,

1. What is the best and efficient method for communication between Server 1 and Server 2.
2. I read something about cURL. Is cURL a better and safe approach for the scenario explained above? Is there any better approach than cURL?
3. In the case cURL is the solution, for continuous server to server data transmission, is it reliable? Will it slow down the response for the client?
4. How efficient is our logic? What are the better methods already available?

Comment: Use REST and JSON, use a framework like Silex/Laravel/Symfony for MVC-approach. cURL is just a library, it (most times) just does http.

Answer (score 0):

The second server is unnecessary if you sanitize the user input data.

If you want to use the second server the communications should either be on a private network.  If the request is sent on the public network you should use HTTPS otherwise the password is vulnerable.
Yes it will slow down the response.  You are injecting a delay by adding another round trip HTTP request.
curl is very reliable, and will do the job just fine. 
`file_get_contents()` would work as well if not better.
Rather than a second server you could make a call to a routine in a private folder not accessible to the public network.

---

**UPDATE**
First off, very few web sites have an data that an attacker might want.  It the data is very sensitive and a attacks are likely then the second server is a good way to protect the data.  I am not a hacker but I can think like one.  Once in awhile there are vulnerabilities that are discovered where the server can be compromised. Or if somehow the MIME type for PHP is misconfigured the PHP code is served as text rather than executed.

An attack would typically be performed by a bot that repeatedly attempts to log in.  There you count the number of times each ip address attempts to log in within a sort period of time.  If they are trying to log in faster than humanly possible, ban the ip.
If the submitted data is properly sanitized, SQL injection is circumvented. I also like to know if someone is attempting an SQL injection by analyzing the data submitted, looking for the common injection keywords. 
I still do not have any idea how I would hack the data on the second server. That would be a good question to ask, Is this second server method vulnerable.
Whenever possible I use non-zero numeric in `<input>` fields then use `intval()` and `floatval()` to sanitize.  I would never use email address as the user name.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable inputs @Misunderstood. The thing which I was worrying is if the first server is attacked it may get the attacker to access the Database right? So that's why I wanna separate the operations from the Database.